# Double title bar Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: gnome, 19.04, window, titlebar

I'm not sure if this is a Ubuntu or Gnome problem, but I just updated the Ubuntu version to 19.04 and noticed that some windows have a double title bar. It does not happen in all of them, but it does happen in the Terminal, File Properties, and some others. I attach a photo.
If it is a configuration thing, I really didn't find where to change it.
I tried the following commands with no success:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

```
sudo apt install --reinstall gnome
```

[image: caption]

Any ideas? Thank you all!

PD: I don't know if it is important, but I had installed 18.04 and update to 18.10 and immediately to 19.04, so I'm not sure if the problem appeared in 18.10.

Comment: Hello @Nmath. The originally installed version was 16.04 (which has unity). From there I upgraded to 18.04 when it came out. And yesterday I tried that 18.04->18.10->19.04 thing. I don't remember changing any config file for GNOME, 
which I understand that it changed quite a bit from its previous version.

Comment: @Nmath, sorry, I forgot to say that I did update all packages & reboot between the upgrades.

Comment: @Nmath, well, I think you solved it! And I was wrong, I was not using GNOME. I purged Unity and reboot. Before I log in, where you can choose different environments, the real GNOME option appeared. I was previously using something just called "Ubuntu", I really don't know what it is that option. So, I chose GNOME, but now the windows didn't have some buttons. I did sudo apt update, then autoremove, and now everything is fine.

Answer (score 5):

I post how I solved the problem, with the help of @Nmath. 
First of all, I was confused about the environment, I was not using GNOME, but something else that was not GNOME nor Unity. It was labeled as "Ubuntu" on the login screen. 
So I run:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt purge unity
```

After reboot, the "real" GNOME appeared as a selectable option on the login screen. I still had some bugs, but where solved with:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

The bugs might have appeared by not doing a clean installation since some versions ago.